# moble app deploy in Ccomonsere

Tags: database, cordova, html5-canvas

hi i develope a mobile app with phonegap frame work and html5,erything works fine but for future exist i need to connect my app to server db to make app multi-user. rit now i just create a local storage by using js which store all the user data in perticular local storage? what are the options i have to make the db server connected do web services work with this if so what kind of service i need to use. itried for few web services but all they are related to web applications. plzz help me thanku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **phonegap** App is like a **Web App**. The advantage that your **phonegap** app has over **Web App**, is that you can access native features (camera, Contact, etc..) of the phone with phonegap, which is not possible with a pure webapp.
 So all the backend services that you can use with web app can be used by your phonegap app.
Now which web servcies you want to uses depends upon your preference.
You can use web services or RESTful service for getting data from the backend.

Comment: so do i need to change the complete code of my app to connect it with web services, can u please pass me some links regarding this web services to connect with app

Comment: all the methods used for web application will work on phonegap. As i said before they are the same. You can use whatever you are comfortable at the backend PHP, JSP, .Net. As long as you use only HTML, CSS and Javascript at the frontend.